# AdMob and pure HTML5-JS Integration

Tags: javascript, android, html, admob, mosync

I have an App build on MoSync Reload - e.g. pure HTML5/JS.
Is there a way to show an AdMob or other ad network ad in my App without Java XML?

The old AdMob HTML tutorial (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1704625?hl=en) is now 404 and they  will serve ads only through Google Play Services.

MoSync have an Ad Api (http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html/group___ads_a_p_i.html) but I cannot figure it out how to show the ad in this pure HTML5/JS.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

No. Admob is for serving ads via native platform mechanisms.